# Why my kubernetes remove worker nodes in NotReady status everyday at 22:00?

Tags: kubernetes

Our company have a kubernetes cluster on Alibaba Cloud which version is v1.14.0. I've found that the worker nodes in Not Ready status will be removed from cluster everyday at 22:00. At first I thought that's because we have cluster-autoscaler deployed in the cluster, so I checked it's config, but didn't find any config will automatic remove nodes in cluster.The infomation of our cluster-autoscaler is listed below.

```
Images:registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/acs/autoscaler:v1.3.1-be4edda
command:
      - command:
        - ./cluster-autoscaler
        - --v=5
        - --stderrthreshold=info
        - --cloud-provider=alicloud
        - --scan-interval=10s
        - --scale-down-delay-after-add=10m
        - --scale-down-delay-after-failure=1m
        - --scale-down-unready-time=1m
        - --ok-total-unready-count=1000
        - --max-empty-bulk-delete=50
        - --expander=least-waste
        - --leader-elect=false
        - --scale-down-unneeded-time=10m
        - --scale-down-utilization-threshold=0.05
        - --scale-down-gpu-utilization-threshold=0.3
        - --skip-nodes-with-local-storage=false
        - --nodes=0:100:private_information
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Somebody set a crontab mission clean the NotReady status nodes.